# How to log transaction data to GA E-Commerce using C#

Tags: c#, e-commerce, google-analytics-api

Currently am using GTag to log the purchase data to Google Analytics E-Commerce. Am using Standard E-Commerce. Now am going to move this process as post processing. (i.e) Need to log the purchase data to GA E-Commerce using C# application. Is there any C# API provided by Google for this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at The Google Analytics Measurement Protocol (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/).

It is working with ecommerce data as well: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/devguide#ecom